# AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData() on pause

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas

I'm currently working on some kind of audio player in Javascript, using the Web Audio API to draw the music frequency (using getByteFrequencyData) onto a canvas.

Everything works fine but now I'd like to capture the canvas as an image with the frequency data drawn on it, without having to play the sound.

So I seek to a specific time:

```
myAudioContext.currentTime = 23; // Or whatever time I need to seek to
```

I then call my function that draws the canvas:

```
draw(); // Simple function that draws, works when the song is playing
```

Since I haven't played my song, the frequency data I get from myAudioContext.getByteFrequencyData is 0.

So here is my question: Is there any way to get the frequency data of an audio file without playing it?

Comment: What do you call `playing`? There is definitely a way to not output the sound to the speakers if that's what you're worried about : don't connect it to the audioContext's `destination`.

Comment: By playing I mean calling the play() method, I don't want to play the audio basically I'm looking for a way to get the frequency data at a specific time, I don't know if that's actually possible.

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out? Currently struggling with the same issue, thanks!